# Pandas Pivot_table KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, keyerror

My data looks like below;

```
  'userID'  'songID'  'rating'
0         0      7171         5
1         0      8637         4
2         0     21966         4
3         0     35821         5
4         0     82446         5
```

My code is below in order to create a pivot_table;

```
ratings = pd.pivot_table(data,
                         index="userID",
                         columns="songID",
                         values="rating")
```

I get a `KeyError:'rating'`

I checked other answers, most of them suggest `.reset_index(),` but it didn't work. I keep getting same error.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `KeyError` means there is no column `rating`, test it by `print (data.columns.tolist())`

Comment: I get this output; ["'userID'", "'songID'", "'rating'"]

Comment: Also, check that the 'values' column is of the same type. pd.melt can create a column with both numeric and character values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem in columns names:

```
print (data.columns.tolist())
["'userID'", "'songID'", "'rating'"]
```

You can `strip` traling `'` by:

```
ratings.columns = ratings.columns.str.strip("'")
ratings = pd.pivot_table(data, index = "userID", columns = "songID", values = 'rating')
```

Answer (score 2):

You columns has extra `quotation mark 'xx'` around. so if you want to keep it then use following

```
ratings = pd.pivot_table(df, index = "'userID'", columns = "'songID'", values = "'rating'")
```